# how to set condition in adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I use this to visible some textview

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post p = posts.get(position);
        holder.textView1.setText(p.getName());
        holder.textView2.setText(p.getFamilyName());
        if (posts.get(position).getBoolean()){
            holder.textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        
    }
```

but when I use `notifyDataSetChange();` I have some problem what is the correct way to set the `if(){}`
in recycler view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the else part .

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Post p = posts.get(position);
    holder.textView1.setText(p.getName());
    holder.textView2.setText(p.getFamilyName());
    holder.textView3.setVisibility(posts.get(position).getBoolean() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Post p = posts . get (position);
    holder.textView1.setText(p.getName());
    holder.textView2.setText(p.getFamilyName());
    holder.textView3.setVisibility(
        if (posts.get(position).getBoolean()) {
            View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            View.GONE
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.